# laravel relationship on delete

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

i am programming laravel app that has three tables

1. categories
2. companies
3. coupons

and **coupons has category_id , company_id for relationship** the thing is when i delete category i want to set in coupons table **the category_id to null** instead of leaving it there because leaving it will cause problems i saw foreigen keys and onDelete but i can't seem to understand it i will share migration and delete method

coupon migration

```
 $table->id();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('link');
        $table->longText('terms');
        $table->string('show_image');
        $table->string('coupon_code');
        $table->tinyinteger('special');
        $table->integer('category_id');
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');;
        $table->integer('company_id');
        $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');;
        $table->timestamps();
```

about the other tables they only have title , image , id so no need to share them

Category Delete function

```
public function destroy(Request $request , $id)
{
    $destroy_category = Categories::find($id);
    //delete the icon
    $icon = $destroy_category->icon;
    File::delete(public_path($icon));
    $destroy_category->delete();
    return redirect('/category/index')->with('success' , 'Category Deleted Successfully');
}
```

please show me how i should set the category_id to null or do something about it

Thanks in advance

Comment: With this type of logic you probably want to look at a model observer for the `deleting` or `deleted` event and use that to null out the field you want to on your related coupons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

- `php artisan make:observer CategoryObserver`
- Open `app/Observers/CategoryObserver.php`
- In the `deleting()` method, put this:

```
    //delete the icon
    $icon = $destroy_category->icon;
    File::delete(public_path($icon));
    $destroy_category->delete();
```

- Open `app/Provivers/AppServiceProvider.php` and place this in the `boot()` method:

```
Category::observe(CategoryObserver::class); //import the class correctly
```

- Change your controller code to this:

```
public function destroy(Request $request , $id)
{
    $destroy_category = Categories::find($id);
    $destroy_category->delete(); //this will fire the CategoryObserver::deleting() method

    return redirect('/category/index')->with('success' , 'Category Deleted Successfully');
}
```

Comment: i will try it but may i ask you for explanation, i mean what does this opserver do

Comment: In Laravel context, it's used for listening for CRUD actions on model. For example, If your application requires to perform certain action each time a model object is created, instead of writing the logic inn various places, you can setup an observe that listens for "create" action, so the method is called whenever model is created. Perhaps you can read up here https://dev.to/hsmobio/what-is-laravel-model-observers-4723

Comment: Why use a observer if it can be solved 8n database side?

Comment: He's trying to delete a file `File::delete(public_path($icon));` when Category is deleted

Comment: NOO you missunderstood me , what i want is when i delete category the category id in my coupons table should be set to null; this is all i want because if it is not null there will be a problem in retrieving records from db , and based on that the code djunehor provided doesn't fit the case

Comment: Then place that logic in the observer method. Set category_id in coupons table to null in the observer method

Comment: but that will require post request to update method and you can't do post request when preforming delete request, and this is the main problem

Comment: It doesn't require post request, use DELETE request as you currently do. If your observer is setup correctly, once you do `$cagetory = Categories::find($id); $category->delete()`, the observe is fired automatically.